# Create a code for a single/multiple choice question with four options, correct answer popup and explanation popup as well

Tags: html

I need to show a single/multiple choice question to a user with a title saying "Question" and in the next line the question.

Then, the four options should be radio buttons (for single answer and checkboxes for multiple answer).

If correct answer is selected

- turn correct answer background to green
- expand the solution and explanation

If wrong answer is selected,

- the background of selected/wrong option should turn red
- the background of right option should turn green
  -expand the solution and explanation

Anyway, the user can expand the answer and explanation without answering the question.

Please provide html, code for thes functionality

Answer (score 0):

Only because I'm thirsty to increase my reputation points, I made a quick solution for your "question" smh

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Simple Quiz</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Q1. What is 9+10?</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="correct">21<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" >22<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" >19<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" >15<br>
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submitQuiz" onclick="result()"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function result(){
            let score=0;
            if (document.getElementById('correct').checked) {
                score++
                document.write("Correct!!! - 9+10 does equal 21 because, if you start with 9 and add 10 to that number it will equal 21")
            } else {
                score--
                document.write("Incorrect bozo! - 9+10 equals 21 because if you start with 9 and add 10 to that number it will equal 21")
            }
        }
            
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Like what Alon Eitan said, "this is not a code writing service".